# could not determine a constructor for the tag '!GetAtt'

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am writing a CFT for a website hosted on S3 - The YML file passes template-validate with no issues however the build agent returns the following error:

`yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!GetAtt'`

```html
Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !GetAtt RootBucket.WebsiteURL
    Description: URL for website hosted on S3
```

Comment: This question may be answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914422/parse-an-aws-cloudformation-template-with-a-yaml-library).

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the shorthand version of Fn::GetAtt

```html
Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: Fn::GetAtt: [ RootBucket, WebsiteURL ]
    Description: URL for website hosted on S3
```