# YAML Error: could not determine a constructor for the tag

Tags: aws-cloudformation, ruamel.yaml

This is very similar to [questions/44786412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786412/could-not-determine-a-constructor-for-the-tag-getatt) but mine appears to be triggered by YAML safe_load(). I'm using Ruamel's [library](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/) and [YamlReader](https://github.com/ImmobilienScout24/yamlreader) to glue a bunch of CloudFormation pieces together into a single, merged template. Is bang-notation just not proper YAML?

```
Outputs:
  Vpc:
    Value: !Ref vpc
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Vpc"
```

No problem with these

```
Outputs:
  Vpc:
    Value:
      Ref: vpc
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-Vpc"

Resources:
  vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock:
        Fn::FindInMap: [ CidrBlock, !Ref "AWS::Region", Vpc ]
```

---

Part 2; how to get load() to leave what's right of the 'Fn::Select:' alone.

```
  FromPort: 
    Fn::Select: [ 0, Fn::FindInMap: [ Service, https, Ports ] ]
```

gets converted to this, that now CF doesn't like.

```
  FromPort:
    Fn::Select: [0, {Fn::FindInMap: [Service, https, Ports]}]
```

If I unroll the statement fully then no problems. I guess the shorthand is just problematic.

```
  FromPort:
    Fn::Select:
    - 0
    - Fn::FindInMap: [Service, ssh, Ports]
```

Comment: You should roll back and remove that 'Part 2'. Tagging on additional questions, even related, is not how [so] works. You could pose it as  a new question, but is very unclear as it is now: which of the seven colons are you referring to? Also "gets converted to below that" , Below what? Below the colon?

Answer (score 7):

Your "bang notation" is proper YAML, normally this is called a *tag*. If you want to use the `safe_load()` with those you'll have to provide constructors for the `!Ref` and `!Sub` tags, e.g. using:

```
ruamel.yaml.add_constructor(u'!Ref', your_ref_constructor, constructor=ruamel.yaml.SafeConstructor)
```

where for both tags you should expect to handle scalars a value. and not the more common mapping.

I recommend you use the `RoundTripLoader` instead of the `SafeLoader`, that will preserve order, comments, etc. as well. The `RoundTripLoader` is a subclass of the `SafeLoader`.

If you are using ruamel.yaml>=0.15.33, which supports round-tripping scalars, you can do (using the new ruamel.yaml API):

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

data = yaml.load("""\
Outputs:
  Vpc:
    Value: !Ref: vpc    # first tag
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Vpc"  # second tag
""")

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

to get:

```
Outputs:
  Vpc:
    Value: !Ref: vpc    # first tag
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Vpc"  # second tag
```

In older 0.15.X versions, you'll have to specify the classes for the scalar objects yourself. This is cumbersome, if you have many objects, but allows for additional functionality:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML


class Ref:
    yaml_tag = u'!Ref:'

    def __init__(self, value, style=None):
        self.value = value
        self.style = style

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag,
                                            u'{.value}'.format(node), node.style)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        return cls(node.value, node.style)

    def __iadd__(self, v):
        self.value += str(v)
        return self

class Sub:
    yaml_tag = u'!Sub'
    def __init__(self, value, style=None):
        self.value = value
        self.style = style

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag,
                                            u'{.value}'.format(node), node.style)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        return cls(node.value, node.style)


yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
yaml.register_class(Ref)
yaml.register_class(Sub)

data = yaml.load("""\
Outputs:
  Vpc:
    Value: !Ref: vpc    # first tag
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Vpc"  # second tag
""")

data['Outputs']['Vpc']['Value'] += '123'

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Outputs:
  Vpc:
    Value: !Ref: vpc123 # first tag
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Vpc"  # second tag
```

Comment: Thanks. I've gotten much farther now that I've removed bang-notation and switched to using RoundTrip. But besides defining said classes (not particularly interested in defining all of CloudFormation's intrinsic functions), is there a way for Yaml to leave anything to the right of the colon alone and not parse it?

Comment: @MatthewPatton No, the parsing needs to be done, to know where the tag ends, what the value associated with it is etc. I updated the catch-all for undefined tagged objects to support scalars (it only supported mapping based object) as you are using and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: "The RoundTripLoader is a subclass of the SafeLoader" -- is it? I can't tell from the source code: https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/loader.py#l58

Comment: @JasonS You should probably post that as a question.