# Merge cloud yaml AWS cloud formation template

Tags: python, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have multiple files that contains my cloud formation `template.yaml` file. For example

base.yaml

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Conditions:
  conFunctionInVPC: !And
    - !Not [!Equals [!Join ["", !Ref parFunctionSubnets], ""]]
    - !Not [!Equals [!Join ["", !Ref parFunctionSecurityGroups], ""]]
  conFunctionNotInVPC: !Not [!Condition conFunctionInVPC]
  conAwsXRaySdkLayer: !Not [!Equals [!Ref parAwsXRaySdkLayerArn, ""]]
```

application.yaml

```yaml
Description: >
  test
  A short description of the function purpose
```

I want to produce the final yaml file. I tried a simple merging function

```py
with open('base.yaml') as f:
    base = yaml.load(f)
with open('application.yaml') as f:
    application = yaml.load(fp)
template = merge(base, template) # my own function not important here
yaml.dump(template, open('template.yaml', 'w'))
```

However I get the error:

> yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!And'

**How can I tell yaml to just keep the node as simple it is? And be able to output it again when dumping it?**

I tried with

```py
yaml.add_multi_constructor('!', lambda loader, suffix, node: node)
```

but then when I dump the file, I get the `SequenceNode` object in my yaml for each `!ref`

for example:

```yaml
conFunctionInVPC: !!python/object:yaml.nodes.SequenceNode
    end_mark: !!python/object:yaml.error.Mark
      buffer: null
      column: 2
      index: 721
      line: 24
      name: template/template.yaml
      pointer: null
    flow_style: false
    start_mark: !!python/object:yaml.error.Mark
      buffer: null
      column: 20
      index: 581
      line: 21
      name: template/template.yaml
      pointer: null
    tag: '!And'
    value:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [YAML Error: could not determine a constructor for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966633/yaml-error-could-not-determine-a-constructor-for-the-tag)

it seems it works using the `RoundTrip` and `ruamel`

```py
template = load(f, Loader=RoundTripLoader)
yaml.dump(template, f, Dumper=RoundTripDumper)
```