# Parse an AWS CloudFormation template with the PyYAML library

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, pyyaml

I am writing a custom Python application using the PyYAML library that needs to read in AWS CloudFormation YAML templates.

I know the templates are valid CloudFormation templates, because I tested them using validate-template:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://cloudformation.yml
```

When I try to read them using the PyYAML library, however, I get errors like:

> yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

and

> could not determine a constructor for the tag "!Sub"

and others.

By way of example, I try this AWS example template:

```
▶ curl -s \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/FindInMap_Inside_Sub.yaml \
    -o FindInMap_Inside_Sub.yaml
```

And then:

```
▶ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Nov 27 2018, 21:40:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load(open('FindInMap_Inside_Sub.yaml'))
```

Which leads to:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!FindInMap'
  in "FindInMap_Inside_Sub.yaml", line 89, column 45
```

**How can I parse a CloudFormation YAML file using a library like PyYAML or others?**

Answer (score 24):

It is possible to use the [cfn_tools](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip/tree/master/cfn_tools) library that ships with the [aws-cfn-template-flip](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip) project.

Install the library:

```
▶ pip install cfn_flip
```

Then the simplest Python to read in the template might be:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
  
import yaml
from cfn_tools import load_yaml, dump_yaml

text = open('./FindInMap_Inside_Sub.yaml').read()
data = load_yaml(text)

print(dump_yaml(data))
```

This library is not really documented but there are also various methods in there for customising the formatting of the output worth exploring.

Answer (score 6):

Their [aws-cfn-template-flip](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip) project that converts cfn templates to/from json and yaml is a good starting point.
Example check out the [yaml_loader.py](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip/blob/master/cfn_tools/yaml_loader.py) script.
It shows how it's adding yaml constructors. 
At the bottom, you'll see:

```
CfnYamlLoader.add_constructor(TAG_MAP, construct_mapping)
CfnYamlLoader.add_multi_constructor("!", multi_constructor)
```

You'll probably be interested in the `construct_mapping` method there. From there, you can look how the code works.

Comment: Thank you so much for these informations. I found another workaround for my specific concern, but they  will probably help me in other automation issues.

Comment: In fact my real matter was to find a solution for AWS cfn templates parameters overrides an serverless applications deployment (artifacts and packages) in AWS Service Catalog, through an infrastructure system I set up with aws Management and CI/CD tools. I definitively decided to separate infrastructure from configuration and parameters, by using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store.
But I'll use these tools you indicated in another stage

I intend to write a full article on what I did and what issues encountered exactly...

Comment: Where is that article ;) ?

Answer (score 4):

I had some trouble with [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55349491/665400), because it was automatically converting my CF template into long form. So any `!Ref Thing` call was being converted into a dictionary mapping.

If you want to match the original input of your `input.template` file, use this:

```py
from cfn_tools import load_yaml
import cfn_flip.yaml_dumper
import yaml


with open('input.template') as f:
    raw = f.read()
    data_dict = load_yaml(raw)

with open('output.template', 'w') as f:
    dumper = cfn_flip.yaml_dumper.get_dumper(clean_up=False, long_form=False)
    raw = yaml.dump(
        data_dict,
        Dumper=dumper,
        default_flow_style=False,
        allow_unicode=True
    )
    f.write(raw)
```

You can also change `clean_up=False` to `True` to perform some smart formatting, which worked well in my case.

I found this after running the cfn cli tool and seeing the correct short form output on my template. Then I used [that main file](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip/blob/master/cfn_flip/main.py) as a reference and followed the code path.

Comment: Thanks for this! Would you happen to know how to keep variables of constructors in the same line? For example, even after using this I'm still not getting the result I want: `- !FindInMap [PrivateLink, EndPoint, SubnetId1]`. Instead I'm getting `- !FindInMap` and then it drops a line and passes the rest of the variables `- PrivateLink - EndPoint - SubnetId1`

Comment: Those 2 things should be functionally equivalent @Daniel, in cloudformation yaml both of those ways are treated as lists. But no I don't know of a way. But I wouldn't bother investigating since it's just stylistic